# Calculate the speed of Halley's comet at his perihelion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, comets

Knowing that Halley's comet orbita the sun every 75,3 years, that the semi-major axes is 17.83 AU, the semi-major axes is 4.53 AU and at his perihelion he is 0.586 AU away from the sun. With these information's we should calculate his speed at his perihelion using Kempler's second law ($\frac{d}{dt}\vec{L}=0=m\frac{d}{dt}(\vec{r}\times\vec{v}$).

I have been trying to form a function for v and r but I just came up with some formula for $v(t)=v_a+\frac{v_p-v_a}{T/2}t$. I just need some kind of hint how to use the second law properly.

Also, can we use that $F_g=F_{cp}\Rightarrow\frac{m\cdot v^2(t)}{r(t)}=\gamma\frac{mM}{r^2(t)}$?

Comment: Are you sure that relation for velocity is right? I think it should have some periodic structure to reflect the fact that the comet is going around the sun periodically.

Comment: The velocity function describes only starting from the aphelion to the perihelion. From there on we just a to -a (acceleration).

Comment: We cannot assume that the acceleration is uniform. In fact the acceleration changes according to the inverse-square law. Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation between velocity v and distance r at which a small body orbits a much larger one of mass M is given by
$v^2 = GM(\frac{2}{r} - \frac{1}{a})$
where a is semi-major axis.

The perihelion is $p = a(1-e)$ where e is the eccentricity, given by
$e^2 = 1 - (\frac{b}{a})^2  $
and b is the semi-minor axis.

If you don't have values for G and M you can use
$GM = (\frac{2\pi}{T})^2\cdot a^3 $ 
where T is orbital period.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_orbit